# How to use \clip on half space?

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I need to limit the display of a complex drawing to the first dial.

I can use

```
\clip (0,0) rectangle (Xmax,Ymax);
```

but in my diagram, Xmax and Ymax are not known and I have to modify them by trial and error.
Is there another solution?

Comment: Maybe `\clip [overlay]
      (0,0) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt);`? This is similar to the proposal in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168.